# single quote added to string when building a mongo string

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to build query string to find documents in mongodb.
I have a variable assigned for the value in the key:value pair.

My code looks like below

```
var query = {"_id":orgId[0]}; 
var name = "_id"; 

console.log(query);

db.collection('orgs')
  .findOne({query}, function (err,result) {

});
```

The value of query looks like the below

```
{ _id: '"567a701be4b017"' }
```

Its basically adding a single quote around the string value and therefor the result from the query is null. How can i get past this ?

Thanks
Sam

Comment: Can you verify that value in `orgId[0]` doesn't actually have a pair of double quotes in it? Perhaps by doing something like this: `console.log(orgId[0] === '"567a701be4b017"')`. If it logs `true` the string itself has extra double quotes, if it logs `false`, something weird is happening.

Comment: You are absolutely right. The orgId[0] actually had a pair of double quotes. Now i modified my code in some earlier steps , so that  orgId[0] doesnot have double quoted strings.
Thanks so much.